# How to connect Google colab, gitHub and pycharm for an assignment

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

For this assignment, we were given starter code in multiple (.py) files. After completing the codes (using Pycharm community), I saved them in my desktop folder.

Next I have to use colab to train my model. However, I am finding it difficult to load my .py files to colab. What should I do next?

Once, I train the model, I need to run local grader to grade my assignment. The grader folder contains again .py files. Will I be able to run them in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Take each step separately. Do online research. If you have actual specific question, here would be the place to ask them. Wide open questions like "What should I do next?" are not for StackOverflow though. Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].